# AWS EC2 (c5n.4xlarge) instance intermitent processing/updating lag

Tags: amazon-web-services

We recently upgraded for more resources on AWS (a week ago). We noticed something baffling and we hope someone has some advice.

***The server will intermittently ignore updates for a few minutes, and then process them without further human interaction***.

The server never stops, meaning users can still interact with the end user website. Pages will load during this "stalled state".

During a "stall" if I upload (using FTP) a simple change to a webpage, say, adding in the text "Hello World!" it will take 3min or so to appear. I refresh the page over and over and eventually Hello World shows up. Normally, such a change would reflect on the webpage instantly.

Also, we have an API that accepts/consumes JSON. Then we have a parsing script to display the JSON on webpage in user friendly format. The parser is trigger on each and every page load on the server. We are seeing the parser not being triggered during these "stalls" even though there are many page loads during this time.

I apologize for describing this like a newbie. We really know what we are doing with AWS. This one has us stumped. Because it's intermittent and when we see it, nothing is happening...it's hard to flush out.

Something must be causing the delay. Looking at Cloudwatch and other measures we never appear to be using more than 20% of CPU or RAM. Bandwidth is 10GBit, we don't do any sort of audio/video/streaming. We do have a massive DB with a website that s 1000's of dynamic pages. However, our old instance worked just fine, it was just getting slow due to use use. Page loads take about 1.5sec.

OK so kinda a long story, but if anyone has any ideas this would be most appreciated. If you need more specs/details I will provide.

Thank you all very much in advance.